# Create dynamic form and submit using Vue + PHP

Tags: php, ajax, vue.js

I have a form that is being created inside a **v-for** and I need to submit a form being created like below but nothing is working. I have used **Ajax** and **Axios** all work fine if the form is outside the **v-for** loop. Can anyone propose a way to go about it. Code below:

```
<div id="classPosts">
<div class="panel panel-default" v-for="single_post in class_posts">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div id="responseDiv">
                            <div class="collapse" :id="`comment_div_${single_post.id}`">
                                <p></p>
                                <br>
                                <form action="#" method="post">
                                    <div class="row" id="comment_div" style="padding-left:20px;padding-right:20px;">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="post_id" id="post_id" :value="`${single_post.id}`">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="user_id" id="user_id" :value="`${single_post.userid}`">
                                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                                            <textarea name="post_comment" id="post_comment" rows="2" style="margin-left: 0px;resize: none;" class="form-control" placeholder="Reply" required v-model="post_comment"></textarea>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                                            <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" id="submitComment" name="submitComment" @click="createComment()">Comment Post</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

The above is where the form is being dynamically created: - : And below is the Vue instance. When I click on Comment Post button, nothing happens and even the ***alert("The Create comment function has been summoned.")***; does not show.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
new Vue({
    el: '#classPosts',
    data: {
        post_comment: '',
        class_posts: []
    },
    methods: {
        loadData: function() {
            ...
    },
    createComment: function() {
        alert("The Create comment function has been summoned.");
    },
    mounted: function() {
        this.loadData();
        setInterval(function() {
            this.loadData();
        }.bind(this), 60000);
    }
});
```

Below is the console.log for class_posts. Return value.

[image]

Comment: Check my answer, please. Most probably, there is a solution.

Comment: Also, check you browser console. It should contain some useful information about an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your problem. You are using this code:

```
methods: {
    loadData: function() {
        ...
},
createComment: function() {
    alert("The Create comment function has been summoned.");
},
```

But your method `createComment` should be inside your `methods` property like this:

```
methods: {
    loadData: function() {
        ...
    },
    createComment: function() {
        alert("The Create comment function has been summoned.");
    },
},
```

**Upd.**

Answering to your question from the comment. At first change your code to this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="post_id" id="post_id" :value="single_post.id">
<input type="hidden" name="user_id" id="user_id" :value="single_post.userid">
```

check it and let me know.

Comment: Thank you, it's working now.  I don't know how i missed that part.

Comment: I however could use your help again, i am seeing that the following lines are only getting the first IDs of the first row in the loop and not changing for all the other items in that v-for loop: ```<input type="hidden" name="post_id" id="post_id" :value="`${single_post.id}`">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="user_id" id="user_id" :value="`${single_post.userid}`">```

Comment: @HueyMataruse, I have updated my answer. Can you check it?

Comment: @HueyMataruse, also, you can show me `console.log(class_posts)` - it would be helpful.

Comment: i have sent the console log,

Comment: @HueyMataruse, have you changed the code like in my example in updates to the answer?

Comment: @HueyMataruse, also, you can't use `v-model="post_comment"` on `textarea` bacause you are trying to bind to the same `post_comment` different textareas.

Comment: yes i changed the code as you mentioned earlier and that is what i got, I am still getting IDs from the first object only i.e 6 & 71 but those of the second object 5 & 71 even if the v-for is implemented. Yes the post_comment binding i was having issues too with that, how can I address it, can i use ```refs```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206816/discussion-between-huey-mataruse-and-webprogrammer).

Answer (score 1):

prevent the page to reload when you are clicking that button. Your comment post button must be .

```
<button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" id="submitComment" name="submitComment" @click.prevent="createComment()">Comment Post</button>
```

Comment: I have done that but still not working but thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Really ? It's impossible

Comment: You were rught @ Qonvex620, it's just that I had missed another curly brace to nest my function inside methods.